# Tangent plane of $f(x,y,z)$? How is this possible?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am in vector calculus right now and am confused as to the following problem. From my understanding, this cannot have a tangent plane as it is a function of three variables, and would instead give a surface. However, the book asks for a tangent plane. More frustratingly, this problem is an even problem (no solution available) and there aren't any similar to it in the text. All others ask for a tangent plane of $f(x,y)$.

Should I use the derivative matrix of the function and then use the linear approximation as my "tangent plane"? Or rather solve the equations for $z = f(x,y)$ and then go from there. Thanks for any input.

> Compute the tangent plane of the following function at $(1,0,1)$
>     $$
>         \ f(x,y,z) =\frac{xyz}{x^2 + y^2 +z^2}
>         $$

Comment: It probably means "compute the tangent hyperplane". The graph of your function is four dimensional, so its tangent space has also 4 dimensions.

Comment: @hjhjhj57 I think you mean 3 dimensions

Comment: @WilliamStagner yes, The graph is a three dimensional object inside $\mathbb{R}^4$. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm thanks. Think I understand but not sure if I got the right answer. Ill go to office hours and ask for help.

Comment: Could the question be asking about the tangent plane to the level set through $(1, 0, 1)$ at that point?

Comment: The book says literally what I typed which is why I am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y,z)\approx f(1,0,1)+f_x(1,0,1)(x-1)+f_y(1,0,1)y+f_z(1,0,1)(z-1)$

The right hand side is the required tangent plane at the point $(1,0,1)$.

Comment: This is what I ended up getting on my own, so thank you for verifying.